# IChartStorageHandler implementation, handler does not trigger

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, httphandler, mschart, charts

I'm trying to implement **IChartStorageHandler** via .Net4.5/MVC4 application to use on Azure based on http://goo.gl/WAapl

I couldn't be able to hit none of the breakpoints that I set in the class below.  So my question is, "is there any trick that I can use to force it"?  Thank you!

You may find the details about the parameters at  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456629.aspx

```
namespace MvcWebRole1.Codes
{
    public class ChartImageHandler : IChartStorageHandler
    {

        public ChartImageHandler()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        #region IChartStorageHandler Members

        public void Delete(string key)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public bool Exists(string key)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public byte[] Load(string key)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Save(string key, byte[] data)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        #endregion

    }
}
```

web.config part #1

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="handler=MvcWebRole1.Codes.ChartImageHandler, MvcWebRole1; webDevServerUseConfigSettings=false;" />
  </appSettings>
```

web.config part #2

```
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ChartImageHandler"/>
      <add name="ChartImageHandler" path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

controller

```
public ActionResult ChartImage()
{
    // get data 
    string path = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Test.csv");
    IEnumerable<Bar> data = BarRepository.Get(path);

    // generate chart
    byte[] chartResult = data.Generator();

    // return the chart
    return File(chartResult, "image/png");
}

public static class ChartOperations
{
    private static Chart _chart1;

    public static byte[] Generator(this IEnumerable<Bar> data)
    {
        // initial variable tasks
        _chart1 = new Chart() {DataSource =  data.ToList()};

        // generate the chart
        DoTheHardWork();

        // save chart to memory string
        var image = new MemoryStream();
        _chart1.SaveImage(image);
        var result = image.GetBuffer();

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you calling the class? Does the breakpoint hit on the line making the call?

Comment: calling it from controller, and yes it does.

Comment: Could you provide us the controller code?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if you have any entries for ChartImageHandler under system.web/httpHandlers? If yes, then please remove it.

also, it might not relate to this but in you web.config part #1, shouldn't you mention storage=file; as well so as to make it look like :

```
<add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;handler=MvcWebRole1.Codes.ChartImageHandler, MvcWebRole1; webDevServerUseConfigSettings=false;" />
```

Comment: No, I don't have it.  And no it shouldn't be like that since I want to use handler not storage. Handler should give the details. (I may use cloud cache, blob etc.)

Answer (score 0):

This might be a stupid question to ask but when you are trying to hit a break point in your handler are you actually opening a page that includes ASP.NET Charts? The Chart handler will be hit only when charts are being loaded.

Comment: Using MVC and creating the chart at controller.  As long as I call Chart controller it should call handler.  Nothing is different than location setting, if you set it, it should work even you don't have a page control.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could launch the debugger as soon as your class is created?

```
public ChartImageHandler()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
    //throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

More at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch.aspx

Comment: Sorry, that won't work neither.  Since it is not getting into the ChartImageHandler.  If it could, it should be able to throw the exception.